# How to start with Docker, Dockerfile, and Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What's the best practice to use Dockerfile with docker-compose.yml? And how to do CI/CD with Jenkins?

I have 2 microservices and one Postgres database. I create docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  myflashcards-service-dictionary:
    image: myflashcards-service-dictionary
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
```

The question is what to write in "image:" section? Should I first run
`mvn clean install -DskipTests dockerfile:build`? But what with the image name?

I'd like to know how to automate the whole CI/CD.

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ADD target/myflashcards-service-dictionary.jar myflashcards-service-dictionary.jar

ENTRYPOINT exec java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=$profile -jar /myflashcards-service-dictionary.jar

EXPOSE 8092
```

I have also docker-compose.yml but how docker-compose.yml know which image should be used?

Would you briefly outline the main process how to deploy my microservices app to the server?

How to use Dockerfile and docker-compose? When are these files necessary?
Do we need Dockerfile only to create an image in Docker Hub?

Comment: In general, in your `docker-compose.yml` you can use a public image from Docker Hub if you are happy to use an existing image as-is, and you can use a build context if you need to build your own image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is similar to the Maven POM file; its a set of instructions for Docker to create an image with (`docker build image-name .`). **Dockerfile is a must, you cannot use Docker without a one.** It's like trying to use a Maven without a POM file.

> Name of the image is what you give for the Maven plugin (`<repository>spotify/foobar</repository>`) or `docker build <image-name> .` and this can be anything you like.

Docker Compose is a tool that can be used to manage a service, that can be comprised of multiple micro-services. It allows users to create an orchestration plan that can be run later. This allows users to script complex information of the Docker environment like volumes, networking, restart policies and many more.

**Docker Compose file is an optional one and can be replaced with a different alternative like [HashiCorp Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io)** *But Docker Compose is one of the easiest to use, stick to this if you're new to Docker.*

Docker Compose is able to build and use an image at runtime (useful for development) or run an image that already exists in a repository (production recommendation). Full [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) should explain how to write a one.

**Build at runtime**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  myflashcards-service-dictionary:
    build: path/to/folder/of/Dockerfile
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
```

**Run a pre-existing image**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  myflashcards-service-dictionary:
    image: myflashcards-service-dictionary
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
```

> Dockerfile can be used without a Docker Compose, the only difference is that it's not practical to use in production since it considered as a single service deployment. As far as I'm aware, it cannot be used with [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)
>
> As far as CI/CD goes, you can use a Maven plugin like [Dockerfile Maven Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin). You can find the docs [here](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven). This image then can be pushed to a repository like Docker Hub, AWS ECR or even a self-hosted one (I wouldn't recommend this unless you're comfortable with setting up highly secure networks especially if it's not an internal network).